# ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends - anaconda on windows

Tags: paramiko

I am using the Anaconda environment for python.
I have installed the paramiko (v. 2.0.2) and cryptography (v 1.5) modules using the Anaconda Navigator..
When I try to execute this import statement:
import netmiko
I get an error message "ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends"

The total output in the cmd window is:

```
>>> import netmiko
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py", line 3, in     <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\cisco\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\cisco\cisco_ios_ssh.py", line 1, in  <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\ssh_connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 13, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the right order for the commands would be:

```
#apt-get update
#apt-get install python-dev
#apt-get install libffi-dev
#pip install cryptography
```

It solved the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a problem because you don't have libffi-dev installed.  Installing "python-dev" and "libffi-dev" at the OS layer may help.